# Install azure cli via brew not working on mac m1

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1, azure-cli

I am trying to install azure cli on to my mac M1 and getting these issues....

brew install azure-cli

fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
Warning: No available formula with the name "azure-cli".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
It was migrated from homebrew/cask to homebrew/core.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling brew and upgrading everything that I could find from hours of google searches nothing seems to work for me

Answer (score 1):

After trying many thing things this worked for me...

```
rm -rf $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
brew tap homebrew/core
```

Answer (score 1):

For M1 with Monterey, this worked for me:

```
arch -x86_64 brew update && arch -x86_64 brew install azure-cli
```